# Как работать с git large file storage?

Tags: git

Мне нужно открыть папку с медиа файлами но они зашифрованы

```
version https://hawser.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:4d7a214614ab2935c943f9e0ff69d22eadbb8f32b1258daaa5e2ca24d17e2393
size 12345
```

Я скачал программу [git large file storage](https://git-lfs.github.com)

Но я никогда раньше не работал с такой программой поэтому не знаю как это сделать

я читал [документацию](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md) но так и не понял как расшифровать папку с файлами

С командной строки

```
git lfs
```

Не работает 
поэтому мне пришлось запускать его так

```
"C:\Program Files\Git LFS\git-lfs.exe"
```

Но я так и не понял как мне перевести

```
 "C:\Program Files\Git LFS\git-lfs.exe" pointer --file="C:\Users\User\Downloads\img.png" --pointer="C:\Users\User\Downloads\img2.png"
```

Выводит мне что

> error building Git blob OID: exec: "git": executable file not found in
>   %PATH%

Кто нибудь знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: У вас Git for Windows стоит? Он идет уже вместе с git lfs, проверть в Git Bast: `git lfs version`, если выводит значит все ок, и потом в папке с репозиторием можно использовать: `git lfs checkout`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Командная строка не знает команды git поэтому мне приходится использовать файл по ссылке `"C:\Program Files\Git LFS\git-lfs.exe" version` выводит мне
`git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.7; git a526ba6b)`  а `"C:\Program Files\Git LFS\git-lfs.exe" checkout` вывел мне `Error: failed to call git rev-parse --git-dir --show-toplevel: ""
Not in a git repository.`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Теперь я понял что для работы Git LFS нужна программа Git.Но я все равно не понимаю как перевести или скачать картинку. команда `checkout` вывела `Not in a git repository.`

Comment: сделайте `cd` в папку с вашим проектом